# if s,r $\in R$, and sr < 1, is there any theorem that sr < (min|s|, |r|) in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

I am writing the proof of a problem, and I saw this statement, if s,r < 1, and s,r $to R$, sr < min(|s|, |r|). Is this correct?

Comment: Consider if $s<-1$ and $r<-1$. Then $sr=|s||r|> \min(|s|,|r|)$.

Comment: $s = -\frac13, r=-2$ violates all possible combinations of the assumptions in the title and the question body.

Comment: Yes you are right! but if |s|,|t| <1, then 0< s,t<1. Then is there a proof that $|(r-t)^2|\leq |(1-rt)^2|$